# Define an AWS SAM template file with Cognito users pool and authorizer

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless, aws-sam, aws-lambda-integration

I need to define these and I'm not sure how I find out how to do it:

```
- api gateway
- Cognito user pool
- Cognito user pool client
- Cognito authorizer
- lambda function (under the defined gateway) that uses the cognito authorizer
Method and Integration request - pass fields from the IdToken that the Cognito Authorizer  receives to the lambda function
- Method and Integration response (disable lambda proxy integration) - add default headers for all requests (cors + security headers)
```

Comment: There are some AWS docs which you can refer and customised as per your need- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-controlling-access-to-apis-cognito-user-pool.html